# required_if no funciona Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, validación

Tengo un formulario y en mi conponente tengo las siguientes reglas de validacion, pero no se por qué el required_if no funciona (php 8 laravel 8).

```
  $rules= [
                'sale.client_id' => 'required',
                'sale.contrato_id' => 'nullable' ,
                'sale.afip_cbte_id' => 'required',
                'sale.fecha' => 'required|date', 
                'sale.concepto' => 'required',    
                'sale.fservd'  =>'required_if:sale.concepto,>,1',
                'sale.fservh'  =>'required_if:sale.concepto,>,1',
                'sale.fvctop' =>'required',   
                'sale.cbu'  =>'digits:22|required_if:sale.afip_cbte_id,>,80',
                'sale.asociado'  =>'required_if:sale.afip_cbte_id,>,85',
             ];
```

uno de mis campos vista formulario

```
 <select class="form-select" wire:model.defer="sale.concepto" style="width: 100%" >
   <option value="">--Seleccione--</option>                       
   <option value=1>Productos</option>   
   <option value=2>Servicios</option>   
   <option value=3>Productos y Servicios</option>   
 </select>

              <div class="mx-1">  
                   <x-jet-label for="sale.fservd" value="{{ __('Período Desde:') }}"/>
                   <x-jet-input id="fservd" type="fecha" class="mt-1 block w-full form-control shadow-none flatpickr" wire:model.defer="sale.fservd" />
                   <x-jet-input-error for="sale.fservd" class="mt-2" />
               </div>
               <div class="mx-1">  
                   <x-jet-label for="sale.fservh" value="{{ __('Período Hasta:') }}"/>
                   <x-jet-input id="fservh" type="fecha" class="mt-1 block w-full form-control shadow-none flatpickr" wire:model.defer="sale.fservh" />
                   <x-jet-input-error for="sale.fservh" class="mt-2" />
               </div>
```

al Seleccionar 2 (Servicios), debería requerir campos sale.fservd y sale.fservd, pero no lo hace
alguna idea que puede ser?
Se agradece

Answer (score 0):

al cambiar por > por >= ,ahí funcionó